# .NETFramework Omnisharp Linux

Tags: c#, .net, unity-game-engine, mono, omnisharp

I am trying to use Unity on Linux and in Visual Studio Code (OSS to be more specific). But Omnisharp always gives me this error:

`Error: The reference assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1 were not found.`

I've tried installing .NET but I realized I could only install .NETCore on Linux. I've read that I should use mono but now after installing the official Mono package from pacman I still get the same error even after rebooting.

Maybe I should change Omnisharp to look for mono? I'm not sure how this works, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Alright so deleting the solution file got rid of the error I guess that had to be regenerated, still I won't get any intellisense for Unity specific functions

Comment: Omnisharp gives you that error when? when trying to build? please be more specific

Comment: When it starts up, right after opening a project in VSC

Comment: include that in the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downgrading the C# extension in VSC to version 1.21.13 seem to solved all my problems (I've read this solution somewhere online), though I'm not sure if this is the best way to solve the problem.

Comment: please open a bug about this, otherwise downgrading may not work forever, it has to be fixed in the last version